# NUnit API Test Path Parameters getting passed as %7Bid%7D

Tags: c#, string, api, dll, encoding

I have some C# API's from third party vendors and am setting up NUnit test for the same.
Some APIs require path parameters to be passed and when I am trying to pass a string to one such API then the path parameter getting passed is %7Bid%7D instead of the actual string.

Any ideas what the solution might be. The API's are from third party and I am accessing them as dlls in my project.

NUnit Test:

```
[Test, RequiresThread]
public async Task ReadAPI1()
{
string apiInput = "c25c55e9-c266-47e1-9836-10c9f6ca2664";
APIResponse apiResponse = await apiClass.readMethod(apiInput);  
}
```

API Class used in test:

```
public class apiClass
{

public async Task<apiResponse> readMethod(string id)
{
string url = "/path/{id}";
this.PrepareUrl(url, nameof (id), id);
TestApiResponse<apiResponse> r = await this.GET<apiResponse>(url);
if (r.Exception != null && (uint) r.Exception.status > 0U)
throw r.Exception;
return r.Result;
}
}
```

Actual Result: Path parameter getting passed as %7Bid%7D 
Expected Result: Path parameter getting passed as string

Answer (score 0):

[%7B and %7D are "{" and "}" respectively](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) so the issue likely has something to do with

```
this.PrepareUrl(url, nameof (id), id);
```

not replacing and encoding the uri correctly. Without seeing that it's hard to tell for sure though.

Comment: I don't have access to the proprietary code and so cannot dig deeper. Will ask the code owners for solution